# parse error in haskell in where structure

Tags: haskell

I tried to write a function where given two points (in degree), the Great-circle distance will be calculated. For this, degree has to be changed in radian.

beside the code is looking real ugly, ghci is giving me a parse error on input 'rad2grad'
what i am doing wrong?

```
gke  (x1, y1)(x2, y2) = c*rad2grad
                                  where 
                                              c = 111.2225685
                                       rad2grad = (360*arcos ((sin(grad2rad x1)*sin(grad2rad x2) + cos(grad2rad x1)*cos(grad2rad x2)*cos(grad2rad y1 - grad2rad y2)))/(2*pi)
                                    grad2rad x1 = (2*pi/360)*x1
                                    grad2rad x2 = (2*pi/360)*x2
                                    grad2rad y1 = (2*pi/360)*y1
                                    grad2rad y2 = (2*pi/360)*y2
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is whitespace sensitive, so alignment matters. Once aligned, GHCi said,

`parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Which should indicate to you that you might have mismatched brackets (assuming your indentation is correct). You are indeed missing a final closing paren before dividing by `(2*pi)`.

The following compiles:

```
gke  (x1, y1)(x2, y2) = c*rad2grad
  where 
    c = 111.2225685
    rad2grad = (360*arcos ((sin(grad2rad x1)*sin(grad2rad x2) + cos(grad2rad x1)*cos(grad2rad x2)*cos(grad2rad y1 - grad2rad y2))))/(2*pi)
    grad2rad x1 = (2*pi/360)*x1
    grad2rad x2 = (2*pi/360)*x2
    grad2rad y1 = (2*pi/360)*y1
    grad2rad y2 = (2*pi/360)*y2
```

Comment: i am open for suggestions how to make it less ugly . But please, nothing to fancy for i am just a beginner and wouldn't understand much.

Comment: I think your problem (the missing paren) started because of that huge definition for `rad2grad`. Besides getting an editor that matches parentheses for you, you can break it up into smaller chunks to make it more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand sides of equations in a where block must align with each other. So a minimal fix for your indentation problem looks like this:

```
gke  (x1, y1)(x2, y2) = c*rad2grad
                              where 
                                c           = 111.2225685
                                rad2grad    = (360*arcos ((sin(grad2rad x1)*sin(grad2rad x2) + cos(grad2rad x1)*cos(grad2rad x2)*cos(grad2rad y1 - grad2rad y2)))/(2*pi)
                                grad2rad x1 = (2*pi/360)*x1
                                grad2rad x2 = (2*pi/360)*x2
                                grad2rad y1 = (2*pi/360)*y1
                                grad2rad y2 = (2*pi/360)*y2
```

Also, the parentheses on your `rad2grad` line aren't all matched up. Perhaps the very first open parenthesis can be deleted.

This will take care of the parse errors; there are other problems, too, but I think you will be able to find and fix those on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving redundant definitions for `grad2rad` - they will just be ignored. You can write the function like this:

```
gke  (x1, y1)(x2, y2) = c*rad2grad
                          where 
                            c           = 111.2225685
                            rad2grad    = (360*acos ((sin(grad2rad x1)*sin(grad2rad x2) + cos(grad2rad x1)*cos(grad2rad x2)*cos(grad2rad y1 - grad2rad y2)))/(2*pi))
                            grad2rad a = (2*pi/360)*a
```

Comment: How does the function "know" that it can put x1...y2 for a? sorry for the dumb question :). now, after  typing in 4 numbers, i get the mesage "non type-variable argument in the constraint. What does that mean?

Comment: Please, ignor the last part of my question. found my fault.

Comment: @letter You can pass any expression of the appropriate type to `grad2rad`, including `x1`, `y1`, and similar, but also including more complicated stuff like `x1+y1/2` and `verletIntegrate f x1 x2` or whatever.